# VB6 Update Error Sheridan Grid

Tags: vb6

I'm making some changes to a program that was written by another developer, which uses an SSDB Grid.

I'm writing the code for the `BeforeUpdate` method.

```
On Error GoTo BeforeUpdate_Err

Dim ans%

ans% = MsgBox("These changes will be committed to the database. These changes cannot be undone. " & _
                    "Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Changes")

If ans% = 7 Then
    Grd_Collection.CancelUpdate
End If

Exit Sub

BeforeUpdate_Err:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
```

The only other code for the grid is the `InitColumnProps` method.

However, after hitting the `Exit Sub` line, I get an error message "Update Error".

I've searched the code for this being hard-coded but it isn't, so it's coming from the grid.

What is causing the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the `BeforeUpdate` method pass in an integer? `(Cancel As Integer)` or something?

Therefore, you should just be able to change your code (and tidy it up) to this:

```
On Error GoTo BeforeUpdate_Err

If MsgBox("These changes will be committed to the database. These changes cannot be undone. " & _
                    "Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Changes") = vbNo Then

    Cancel = 1
End If

Exit Sub

BeforeUpdate_Err:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
```